# 2000s movie, including an alien with 8 humanoid bodies and single hive mind

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember an American English-spoken movie on TV where one of the characters was an alien that had 8 humanoid bodies and a single mind. I remember a scene at a cafe where some of the bodies were present while some of the other bodies were enjoying a vacation. It called itself "Eight" while each of the members was called by its number. They all dressed mostly the same, with black shirts and white numbers. I'd guess the production is from the late 90's or, at most, early 2000's. It "felt" a bit like the same tone of "The Tick" but a bit more restrained.

Does anyone know which movie/TV series is this from?

Comment: Hi there! That's a bit terse at the moment, could you maybe take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) and add whatever else you could remember? Most importantly, perhaps - when did you watch this? When would have it been produced?

Comment: I'm kind of on the limits of my limited recollection here. It's probably low-fidelity as it is now.

Comment: *"It's so weird, you couldn't make it up*"

Comment: @rbanffy I've rollbacked your edit because it's totally fine to have incorrect assumptions in story-id questions. Might help future searchers with the same "wrong" assumption to find it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably *The Specials* (2000). From the early scriptwriting days of James Gunn (you know, the guy who directed both *Guardians of the Galaxy* movies).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181836/plotsummary) *(formatted a bit for the sake of readibility)*:

> The Specials, the sixth or seventh greatest superhero group in the world, count the geeks and the oddballs among their fans. They don't have the prestige or the money that a group like the Crusaders has. But they've found their niche as the Ringo Starr of superhero teams.
>
> - There's the Weevil, the most popular member and the one pursued by other teams;
> - the blue-skinned, foul-mouthed Amok;
> - Minute (My-noot) Man, who is sensitive about his oft-mispronounced name;
> - the ever-sneering Deadly Girl;
> - the naive and boyish U.S. Bill;
> - the Strobe, the leader of the team;
> - the Strobe's wife, Ms. Indestructible, who is having an affair with the Weevil;
> - the irritatingly perky Power Chick;
> - the green-skinned weirdo, Alien Orphan;
> - the fat and pompous Mr. Smart;
> - **and Eight, who has eight different bodies.**
>
> The new member is a longtime fan who calls herself Nightbird. Unfortunately, she joins just when Cosgrove Toys creates a new line of action figures based on the Specials. The company's disastrous press conference could mean the end to this cut-rate super-group.

"Eight" replicas have black shirts with white numbers. Image courtesy of [this review](https://risus-mysterymen.neocities.org/inspirations/specials/index.html) introducing all the "Specials", and mentioning *8 Bodies with a Single Consciousness & Group Intelligence* as one of Eight's clichés.

[image: eight replicas of the character, wearing black shirts with white numbers]

---

Found with the Google query `movie alien "eight * bodies"` which returned [this website](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film652990.html).

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. For the record this film is wonderful

Comment: interesting tidbit: Box office $13,276

Comment: @ths for a budget of $1 million if IMDb is correct? Ahahah, that must've stung :D

Comment: @Jenayah - The studio shelved it for a year, then dumped into a handful of theatres so they could get it into Blockbuster and onto PPV as a "cinematic release" (a [trick that studios are still using today](https://www.theguardian.com/film/filmblog/2016/jul/14/emma-watson-the-colony-not-meant-to-be-box-office-hit)). It's one of the earliest movies with a multi-media tie-in website. On the commentary track Gunn mentions that the budget was nothing like a million dollars and that it made a profit.

Comment: @Valorum considering it was allegedly filmed in two weeks (but IMDb has proven to be mistaken, innit), this makes sense. Sounds goofy stupid enough so that I'll make it a watch one of these days anyway :P today I learned...

Comment: @Jenayah - Watch it ***tonight***. It's on Dailymotion in two pieces